# Writing to different sockets in the same time using async_write

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I'd like to write server (TCP/IP) and i have some questions because I am not sure if I think properly.

I need a server with only one thread. I need to read and write data to some clients. I'd like to use `async_accept`, `async_write`, `async_read` etc. from `boost::asio`.

Is it OK in case of calling `async_write` for different clients in the same time? What if my program calls `async_write` for one client and before handler is called it calls `async_write` for another client?

The same question about `async_read`.

Isn't it problem?

Is it warranted (in this case) that callback from first calling `async_write` will be called before callback from second `async_write`?

What if some callback (handler) takes long time? Other callbacks just wait in a stack until this one will be finished? And if this callback never ends another callbacks will be never executed? Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with overlapping async read and write calls to different sockets. I would recommend you give each connection its own strand so that things won't break in the future should you decide to add TLS support or use more than one thread. The completion handlers can be called in any order, depending on the order in which the operations actually complete. Of course, you cannot have two async read operations or two async write operations on the same connection at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

- No, it isn't a problem.
- No, it isn't warranted.
- No, callbacks should not wait for each other.
- No, you aren't right.

Socket I/O proceeds independently for each socket.

Comment: If some callback/handler (from async_write) that is called first in my program will never finish how is it possible that other callback will be executed? Callback are asynchronous on one thread?

Comment: No, you're assuming that. They are asynchronous, period. 'One thread' is your own invention.

Comment: The callback won't be executed until the async operation completes.

Comment: @David Schwartz . Yes I know. But what in situation. I have 2 clients and I write to them (async_write). Writing to the 1st client is done and callback is called. During this time writing to the 2nd client is done. If processing 1st callback takes 1h I thought that 2nd callback will be executed when 1st is finished. EJP said that I'm not right. How is it possible? Are there  really two threads (one for each callback)?

Comment: @peter55555 You can create as many threads as you want. 1, 2, or more. You should never do any more work in a callback than you absolutely have to. If you have a situation where a callback can take more than a very small amount of time, you're probably doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @David Shwartz. Thanks. But I want only 1 thread. Exactly what I wrote in the description to main question. So in this case callbacks behave like 'normal' program and wait for each other? Sorry, I can hardly understand how Asio library really works.
Maybe I explain. What if I need to write to the same file in this callbacks? (Using for example posix functions) Is it safe? 
I write one more time - I won't explicitly create any threads (just like here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html)

Comment: I honestly can't figure out what you're asking. A callback should do as little as possible. If you have something to do that might take a lot of time, the callback is not the right place to do it. You can have only one thread for the `io_service` if you want, or you can have multiple threads. If you have only one thread, and your callback blocks, then you can't do anything else, so having only one thread and doing "real work" in your callbacks is a horrible design.